# R removewords tm treats stop word file as regex not verbatim

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

How can I force removeWords from library(tm) to take each word in a stop word list verbatim (literally), not as a regex?

Suppose I have a file stopwordlist.txt containing characters that can be misinterpreted as regular expressions:

```
 e.g.
 "
 .net
 ...
 \
 ***p<
```

This is my code

```
library(tm)
...
custom_stopwords <- read.delim2("stopwordlist.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "\n", quote = "", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
...
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeWords, custom_stopwords$V1)
```

I would expect removeWords to take each line as a verbatim stop word, for example to remove each occurrence of "e.g." and not the word "ergo" when taken as a regexp. Having some special characters confuses the interpreter saying it is not a valid regexp.

Comment: I know it is not what you are looking for, but you can get a workaround by recognizing that it _does_ treat the stopwords as regexs and instead write your word as `"e\\.g\\."`

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I need to treat the word list verbatim, because it is used in different scripts that rely on it not being a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try creating an alternate version of the stop list just to use with removeWords that includes the escape characters? This way at least you don't need to manually change every '.' to '\.'

```
escaped_stopwords<-gsub("(\\.|\\*|\")", "\\\\\\1", custom_stopwords$V1, perl=T)
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work as a temporary fix. However the stop word lists change frequently and must be maintained simultaneously, which is error prone.